how to use useParams() inside of useEffect
I want to load different components on component mount based on the URL params but my useParams() object room is showing as undefined in my useEffect() for some reason.
// App.js
function App() {
  const { room } = useParams();
  const [inGame, setInGame] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(room); // undefined

    socket.emit("am_i_in_game", room, (res) => {
      setInGame(res.inGame);
      return;
    });

    return;
  }, [room]);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/:room" 
            element={
              inGame ? <GameScreen {...gameScreenProps} />
              : room?.length === 6 ? (
                <StartScreen {...{
                  ...startScreenProps, 
                  hasJoinEmbed: true
                }} />
              ) : <StartScreen {...startScreenProps} />
            } 
          />
        </Routes>
    </ThemeProvider> 
  );


Is App rendered on or below a Route that defines a path prop with a room parameter that it can read from? If it doesn't then it makes sense that room is undefined. Are you trying to read the room path parameter of the Route that App itself is rendering?

@DrewReese no App is the top parent that declares routes.. I see why room is undefined now..

The App component can't read a route path parameter from a route rendered below itself.
I suggest creating a Room component that is rendered on path="/:room" and can read the room route path parameter and issue the side-effect and render the appropriate content. Basically move the state and logic in App down the ReactTree.
Example:
const Room = () => {
  const { room } = useParams();
  const [inGame, setInGame] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(room);

    socket.emit("am_i_in_game", room, (res) => {
      setInGame(res.inGame);
      return;
    });
  }, [room]);

  return inGame
    ? <GameScreen {...gameScreenProps} />
    : (
      <StartScreen
        {...startScreenProps}
        hasJoinEmbed={room?.length === 6}
      />
    );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/:room" element={<Room />} />
      </Routes>
    </ThemeProvider> 
  );
}

